# php - update foreach variable inner it

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

`$colors = array("red", "green");`

I am using this array in `foreach` and I want to update this array inner the `foreach` for example like this:

```
foreach( $colors as $color ){
    if( $color=='green' ){
        array_push($colors, 'blue');  //now $colors is ["red", "green", "blue"]
    }
    echo $color . "<br>";
}
```

Result is:

```
red
green
```

and `blue` is not echo in result!

How I can update `foreach` variable inner it?

---

**update:**
I do this with `for` and it is work.

```
$colors = array("red", "green");

for( $i=0; $i < count($colors); $i++ ){
    if( $colors[$i]=='green' ){
        array_push($colors, 'blue'); //now $colors is ["red", "green", "blue"]
    }
    echo $colors[$i]."<br>";
}
```

result is

```
red
green
blue
```

How I can do this with `foreach`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work may be worth a read to see how `foreach` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass as reference (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) (see `&$color`) it will work as it will point to the same memory address, thus updating the `$colors` var:

```
<?php
$colors = array("red", "green");
foreach( $colors as &$color ){
    if( $color=='green' ){
        array_push($colors, 'blue');
    }
    echo $color . "<br>";
}
```

Of course there is no need for this if you print `$colors` outside the loop, with `print_r($colors);`. This pass by reference is only needed inside the loop.

Comment: I had forgotten that it behaved that way with the reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($colors as $color){
   if( $color=='green' ){
      $colors[]= 'blue';  //now $colors is ["red", "green", "blue"]
   }
}
```

Now use foreach loop to print all values under $color variable

```
foreach($colors as $color){
   echo $color."\n";
}
```